# How summation is changed in Analytic number theory

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, summation, analytic-number-theory

Consider this expression S(x, z) = $\sum_{n\leq x} \sum_{{d|n , d|P(z) } }\mu(d)  $ . I don't understand the logic behind next step and get really confused on how summation is changed.

> In  next step author writes $\sum_{n\leq x} \sum_{{d|n , d|P(z) } }\mu(d)  $  = $ \sum_{d| P(z), d \leq x }\mu(d) \sum_{n\leq x, d|n } 1 $ .

My thoughts: It is clear to me that 1 variable is d and 1 is n. I understand 1st summation from left , $d| P(z) , d\leq x $  and how n$\leq x$ is used but I don't understand why author wrote d|n in 2 nd summation.

Can you please explain it in detail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sometimes, one way to approach switching orders of summation is to make indices completely independent by introducing functions that give conditions.

For example, we might write

$$ \sum_{n \leq x} \sum_{\substack{d \mid n \\ d \mid P(z)}} \mu(d) =
\sum_{n \leq x} \sum_{d \leq x} 1_{[d \mid n]} 1_{[d \mid P(z)]} \mu(d).
\tag{1}$$
Here, I use a form of [Iverson Bracket notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket) of the form
$$ 1_{[\text{condition}]} = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{condition is true,} \\ 0 & \text{else.} \end{cases}$$
In this form, the two regions of summation are independent, and so we can swap the order of summation in $(1)$ without problem. So

$$
\sum_{n \leq x} \sum_{d \leq x} 1_{[d \mid n]} 1_{[d \mid P(z)]} \mu(d) =
\sum_{d \leq x} \mu(d) 1_{[d \mid P(z)]} \sum_{n \leq x} 1_{[d \mid n]}  \mu(d) =
\sum_{\substack{d \leq x \\ d \mid P(z)}} \mu(d)
\sum_{\substack{n \leq x \\ d \mid n}} 1,
$$
as the author claimed.

Comment: consider  $\sum_{d| P(z), d \leq x }\mu(d) \sum_{n\leq x, d|n } 1$  which will be equal to $\sum_{d | P(z) , d\leq x} \mu(d) ×( x/d+O(1)) $  which is equal to $\sum_{d | P(z) , d\leq x} \mu(d) ( x/d) +O(1) $ but I don't know how author writes it equal to $\sum_{d| P(z)  , d\leq x } x/d +O(1) $ ? Can you please explain.

Comment: The first sum to the second sum is because $\sum_{n \leq x, d \mid n} 1 = \lfloor x / d \rfloor = x/d + O(1)$. As written, the next step isn't quite true. I think the best that one can do is to naively bound the sum by $\sum_{d \mid P(z), d \leq x} 1 = O(\min(d(P(z)), x) = O(x^\epsilon)$ for any $\epsilon > 0$, where here $d(P(z))$ is the number of divisors of $P(z)$. If the implicit constant in $O(\cdot)$ is allowed to depend on $z$, then the author's claim is true. If this remains unclear, then I suggest writing a new question focusing on that, as it's quite different.