# A question related to behavior of mobius function $\mu(d)$

Tags: number-theory, summation, analytic-number-theory, mobius-function

This is a continuation of [a previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4208365/9754).

Consider the sum $\sum_{d|P(z),d≤x}μ(d)\sum_{n≤x,d|n}1$, which is clearly equal to $\sum_{d|P(z),d≤x}μ(d)×(x/d+O(1))$. A text I'm reading claims this is equal to $\sum_{d|P(z),d≤x}μ(d)(x/d)+O(1)$, but I don't understand this step.

How does one show that the last step, that this sum is equal to $\sum_{d|P(z),d≤x}x/d+O(1)$?

Comment: Also, what text are you reading?

Comment: @davidlowryduda Zeev rudnick sieve theory notes ( on university of tel aviv website).

Comment: I think you misunderstand. When I ask what text you're reading, I want to see if it is possible to read the text myself *and* so that if other people search for the same problem in the text, then they can find it. I believe you are referring to Zeev Rudnick's notes on the Selberg Sieve from his 2015 course: http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~rudnick/courses/sieves2015/selbergsieveintro.pdf (although actually this part is on the Sieve or Eratosthenes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this question comes from Zeev Rudnick's 2015 lecture series on sieves (notes available [here](http://www.math.tau.ac.il/%7Erudnick/courses/sieves2015.html)), and in particular from the [lecture on the Selberg Sieve](http://www.math.tau.ac.il/%7Erudnick/courses/sieves2015/selbergsieveintro.pdf).

I'll note that these notes have two typos on the same line, both of which are fixed later. Rudnick writes
$$ \begin{align}
S(x, z) :=& \sum_{n \leq x} \sum_{\substack{d \mid n \\ d \mid P(z)}} \mu(d) 
= \sum_{\substack{d \mid P(z) \\ d \leq x}} \mu(d) \sum_{\substack{n \leq x \\ d \mid n}} 1 \\
=& \color{#cb4154}{\sum_{\substack{d \mid P(z) \\ d \leq x}} \frac{x}{d}} + \color{#228b22}{O(1)}
\end{align}$$
as the last displayed equation in page 2 of those notes. The first equality is the subject of [a previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4208365/9754). I have colored two parts on the last line, as each have a mistake (or are confusingly written).

The red part is missing $\mu(d)$, i.e. it should read
$$
\color{#cb4154}{\sum_{\substack{d \mid P(z) \\ d \leq x}} \frac{x}{d}} \to \sum_{\substack{d \mid P(z) \\ d \leq x}} \mu(d)\frac{x}{d},
$$
and the green part is actually still part of the sum, i.e. it should read
$$
\color{#228b22}{O(1)}
\mapsto
\sum_{\substack{d \mid P(z) \\ d \leq x}} O(1).
$$

This is also how Rudnick uses them later. After determining that one can choose $P(z) \leq x$ at the top of page 3, (and thus remove the $d \leq x$ bounds from the sums), Rudnick writes that
$$
S(x, z) \leq x \sum_{d \mid P(z)} \frac{\mu(d)}{d} + O(\sum_{d \mid P(z)} 1),
$$
which is what you get if you use the corrected versions noted above.